# PostgreSQL pg_dump -E encoding option not working

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, encoding

I have a `UTF8` database `qdb` and I want to back it up to a plain file using the same `UTF8` encoding. I am using `pg_dump` as I don't have `pgAdmin` working now. I however can't get `pg_dump` to output a `UTF8`-encoded plain SQL dump file, as this is not working:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin> .\pg_dump.exe -U postgres -F p -O -c -C -E UTF8 qdb > d:\qdb.sql
```

The output dump file is encoded as `UCS-2 LE BOM` nonetheless, which makes some German accented letters display incorrectly. I am using Windows 10 and PostgreSQL 12.4. How can we make `pg_dump` actually dump a plain SQL UTF8 file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forcing a BOM and UTF-16 encoding for redirected output can be done somehow by Windows shells (personally I've experienced this with Powershell and Windows 10).
See e.g. [Resolve UTF-8, UTF-16, ASCII inconsistencies](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/707) for some context.

In the case of `pg_dump`, using the `-f` option to specifiy the output file instead of a shell redirection seems like a good idea against that sort of problem. From the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html):

> -f file
> --file=file
>
> Send output to the specified file. This parameter can be omitted for file based output formats, in which case the standard output is
> used.

Comment: I just hit this same issue and it looks like shell translation was the culprit, thank you so much for this post. As an added bonus, using -f rather than shell redirection reduced the dump time for my database from around 90s to 10s!